# how to modify tf.data.batchDataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I'm looking for a way to modify a time-based dataset obtained by merging multiple time series (window and interleave).

### TLDR;

The time series don't overlap, creating windows/tensors that contain NaNs.  I'm looking for a way to remove them from the batch dataset, altering the batches' size.

---

### More details

Here is an example of the data I'm working with:
Each dataset pertains to an object that sends some features' values through time.
The objects are not necessarily online at the same time, as depicted below.

```
| dataset 1           | dataset 2           | dataset 3           |       | dataset (window, batch, interleave)                                      |
| ------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |       |------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| feature1 | feature2 | feature1 | feature2 | feature1 | feature2 |       | feature1                          |  feature2                            |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |       | --------------------------------- | ------------------------------------ |
|    11    |   101    |    12    |   102    |          |          |       |[[11, 21], [12, 22],   [nan, nan]] | [[101, 201], [102, 202], [nan, nan]] |
|    21    |   201    |    22    |   202    |          |          |       |[[21, 31], [22, 32],   [nan, 33]]  | [[201, 301], [202, 302], [nan, 303]] |
|    31    |   301    |    32    |   302    |    33    |   303    |  -->  |[[31, 41], [32, 42],   [33, 43]]   | [[301, 401], [302, 402], [303, 403]] |
|    41    |   401    |    42    |   402    |    43    |   403    |       |[[41, 51], [42, 52],   [43, 53]]   | [[401, 501], [402, 502], [403, 503]] |
|    51    |   501    |    52    |   502    |    53    |   503    |       |[[51, 61], [52, 62],   [53, 63]]   | [[501, 601], [502, 602], [503, 603]] |
|    61    |   601    |    62    |   602    |    63    |   603    |       |[[61, 71], [62, nan],  [63, 73]]   | [[601, 701], [602, nan], [603, 703]] |
|    71    |   701    |          |          |    73    |   703    |       |[[71, 81], [nan, nan], [73, 83]]   | [[701, 801], [nan, nan], [703, 803]] |
|    81    |   801    |          |          |    83    |   803    |       |[[81, 91], [nan, nan], [83, 93]]   | [[801, 901], [nan, nan], [803, 903]] |
|    91    |   901    |          |          |    93    |   903    |
```

Because all objects are not present at the same time and the window is a parameter of the time series, we'll contend with "incomplete" tensors that contain NaNs.
I want to remove those incomplete tensors while keeping the time-based batching; I need to ensure that all data in a batch trace back to the same point in time.

desired output:

```
| dataset (window, batch, interleave, re-batch)                         |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| feature1                       |  feature2                            |
| ------------------------------ | ------------------------------------ |
| [[11, 21], [12, 22]]           | [[101, 201], [102, 202]]             |
| [[21, 31], [22, 32]]           | [[201, 301], [202, 302]]             |
| [[31, 41], [32, 42], [33, 43]] | [[301, 401], [302, 402], [303, 403]] |
| [[41, 51], [42, 52], [43, 53]] | [[401, 501], [402, 502], [403, 503]] |
| [[51, 61], [52, 62], [53, 63]] | [[501, 601], [502, 602], [503, 603]] |
| [[61, 71], [63, 73]]           | [[601, 701], [603, 703]]             |
| [[71, 81], [73, 83]]           | [[701, 801], [703, 803]]             |
| [[81, 91], [83, 93]]           | [[801, 901], [803, 903]]             |
```

I can't find a good way to achieve that goal.

Do you have any ideas to share?

for info, the real dataset is

- 10's k objects
- 100's features
- 10 k time points
- window size is a parameter I'm experimenting with.

---

### I thought of:

a- creating a layer in the model to discard any tensor that has NaNs...
How to conditionally and safely "disappear" an input from a tf.keras.layers.Layer?
I also think it's cleaner if that type of processing is made upstream from the model itself.

b- using map_fn to remove the incomplete tensors:

```
    theSample = theDS.take(1).get_single_element()

    theMask = {_k: tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(_v), axis=-1)) for _k, _v in theSample.items()}
    theResult = {_k: tf.boolean_mask(theSample[_k], theMask[_k]) for _k in theSample.keys()}
    theResult
```

```
but map_fn doesn't handle datasets.
```

c- clean and rebuild the batchDataset, batch by batch (make a pandas.Dataframe out of the cleaned dataset then make a batchDataset)

```
    def cleanBatch (aBatchedDS):
        # 
        # cleanBatch processes the batched dataset by removing, in each batch, any innermost tensor that contains a 'nan'
        # The sequence between batches needs to be preserved.
        # :param aBatchedDS:
        # :return:
        
        import tensorflow as tf
        import pandas as pd

        theCleanDSList = []
        # Because we want the batch sequence preserved, we need to iterate on the batches.
        for theBatch in aBatchedDS:
            theMask = {_k: tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(_v), axis=-1)) for _k, _v in theBatch.items()}
            theCleanBatch = {_k: tf.boolean_mask(theBatch[_k], theMask[_k]) for _k in theBatch.keys()}
            theCleanDSList.append(theCleanBatch)

        theDSbatched = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(theCleanDSList).to_dict(orient="list"))
        return theDSbatched
```

```
but...
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [2,2] != values[2].shape = [3,2] [Op:Pack] name: component_0
```

d- using tf.data.experimental.dense_to_ragged_batch to force the original batchDataset into a Ragged-batchDataset then remove the "incomplete" tensors

```
    def Ragged_cleanBatch (aBatchedDS):
        # 
        # cleanBatch processes the batched dataset by removing, in each batch, any innermost tensor that contains a 'nan'
        # The sequence between batches needs to be preserved.
        # :param aBatchedDS:
        # :return:
        
        import tensorflow as tf
    
        theCleanDSList = []
        theBatch = None
        # Because we want the batch sequence preserved, we need to iterate on the batches.
        for theBatch in aBatchedDS: # try aBatchedDS.enumerate()
            theMask = {_k: tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(_v), axis=-1)) for _k, _v in theBatch.items()}
            theCleanRaggedBatch = {_k: tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(tf.boolean_mask(theBatch[_k], theMask[_k]), padding=None) for _k in theBatch.keys()}
            theCleanDSList.append(theCleanRaggedBatch)
    
        theFeaturesSpecifications = {_k: tf.io.RaggedFeature(tf.float32) for _k in theBatch.keys()}
        theDSbatched = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(theCleanDSList).to_dict(orient="list"))
        return theDSbatched
```

```
but...
    ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

The transformation, it turns out, is to happen just before the "model.fit" by feeding the model the data through a tf.keras.utils.Sequence

Here is the one I'm using to answer the question I posted:

```
class timeSeriesSequencer(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, aBatchedDS, aLookback, aPredictionsCnt, aHorizon, aLabelsList):

        self.gOut = "_out"
        self.gLabelsList = [f"{_L}{self.gOut}" for _L in aLabelsList]
        self.gInputsSlice = slice(0, aLookback)
        self.gLabelsSlice = slice(aLookback + aHorizon - aPredictionsCnt, None)

        self.mCleanBatchList = self.generateCleanBatches(aBatchedDS)
        self.mSplits = self.splitBatches(self.mCleanBatchList)


    def generateCleanBatches (self, aBatchedDS):
        theCleanBatches = []
        for theBatch in aBatchedDS:
            theMask = {_k: tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.reduce_any(tf.math.is_nan(_v), axis=-1)) for _k, _v in theBatch.items()}
            theCleanBatch = {_k: tf.boolean_mask(theBatch[_k], theMask[_k]) for _k in theBatch.keys()}
            if sum([_T.shape[0] for _T in theCleanBatch.values()]) > 0: 
            # if there is at least one tensor left
                theCleanBatches.append(theCleanBatch)

        return theCleanBatches


    def splitBatches (self, aBatchList):
        theList = []
        for theBatch in aBatchList:
            theStackedWindowPanes = tf.stack(list(theBatch.values()), axis=0)
            thePanesNames = theBatch.keys()
            # Split the time window between the input and the labels
            theInputsPanes = theStackedWindowPanes[:, :, self.gInputsSlice]
            theLabelsPanes = theStackedWindowPanes[:, :, self.gLabelsSlice]

            # Rebuild the Inputs as a batch window. The features in the Labels need to be filtered.
            theWindowInputs = {f"{theName}": thePane for theName, thePane in
                               zip(thePanesNames, tf.unstack(theInputsPanes))}

            theWindowLabels = {f"{theName}{self.gOut}": thePane for theName, thePane in
                               zip(thePanesNames, tf.unstack(theLabelsPanes))
                               if (self.gLabelsList is None or f"{theName}{self.gOut}" in self.gLabelsList)}

            theList.append((theWindowInputs, theWindowLabels))
        return theList


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mCleanBatchList)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.mSplits[idx]
```